# Name of slide over UI pattern or component

Tags: ios, user-interface, slack

In the Slack app for iOS, if you swipe right you get a "drawer" bit of UI containing a page view controller.  But if you swipe left, instead of the main view sliding most of the way off screen, you have another view slide out over the top of the main view.

What is the name of this slide-over UI component?  Is it a standard native component, or a custom 3rd party component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/dpslidemenukit-swift) component. Basically a menu slider with different views

Comment: Yes - exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you.  So I take it there isn't a version of this already available as a standard cocoa touch control.  And "slide menu" seems like a good name for it.

Comment: There isn't a standard control that can do this "out of the box". But you can implement it using [`UIPageViewController `](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller)